# when requesting http in arduino javascript document ready

Tags: javascript, http, request, arduino-esp8266

I am requesting a web page with wifi using ESP 8266.
When this page is loading will the javascript on this page be activated?
Should I expect the 'document.ready' to be fired?

Thanks in advance for any info and/or supporting push to get my quest for an answer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> I am requesting a web page with wifi using ESP 8266

The hardware you use is more-or-less irrelevant.

> When this page is loading will the javascript on this page be activated?

That depends on the software you are making the request with. It would have to be something that ran JavaScript for the JS to run.

(e.g. if you were using Google Chrome, then the JS probably would run but if you were just using cURL then it would not).

Speculation: You are making the HTTP request with a C++ HTTP library and not a web browser. You won't have any JS support.

Comment: Yes! Your speculations are correct!

I am very inexperienced in Arduino http connectivity and right now just following any code example that I found. I use HTTPClient with http.GET or http.Post requests.


What would be the right scenario to request web page containing a function written in JavaScript which could be activated in document.ready ?

Comment: To rewrite the page being requested so the work was done server-side instead. ESP8266's are not designed for the kind of heavy lifting needed for jQuery.

Comment: I am beginning getting the message.
So were for starters should I search for a push in direction of learning how to rewrite the target web page?

Comment: "Server side programming" in combination with whatever programming language you want to use.

Comment: Thanx, Quentin.
I will follow given trail.